# time capsule as linux file system?

Tags: time-capsule

is it reasonable to use a Time Capsule not as a backup, but as a filesystem for a variety of linux/osx computers on the same local network?

(is HFS+, which seems to be claimed to be the default format, a network file system, so that it handles multiple computer access?)

about two years ago, [Can I use my Time Capsule with other OSes?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49547/can-i-use-my-time-capsule-with-other-oses) was concerned with backing up to the Time Machine.  this is not my plan.  it is supposed to be a shared file system.  another post hinted that to use SMB (which both OSX and Linux can use), one would have to set up another partition (or presumably an external USB drive), so I would have to know how much to give to one vs another.

/iaw